# How to view UTF-8 Unicode characters in VIM

Tags: vim, unicode

I am using VIM 7.4 on an Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit machine. In my .vimrc file, I have the following lines:

```
" Use UTF-8 without BOM
set encoding=utf-8 nobomb
```

The `config` file basically uses Unicode character to display white spaces like tabs, new lines, etc. The complete .vimrc file is taken from Paul Irish's [dotfiles](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulirish/dotfiles/master/.vimrc).

On an earlier install of 14.04 as well as in previous distributions, I was able to see the unicode characters without any problems but not with this one.

I also tried:

```
 set fileencodngs=utf-8
```

But, the above setting has no effect and I still see garbled characters on the screen. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Can you give a link to an example file that looks garbled to you? And can you include a screenshot of what you are seeing in vim? What is the value of the `fenc` variable after opening a file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If your current [locale](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/mbyte.html#locale) is in an [utf-8](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/mbyte.html#utf-8) encoding, Vim will automatically start
in utf-8 mode.

If you are using another locale, set below in your user `~/.vimrc` file:

```
set encoding=utf-8
```

You might also want to select the font used for the [menus](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#menus).  Unfortunately this
doesn't always work.

Also you have this option to force encoding with `:set fileencodings=utf-8`. You can find the documentation [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27fileencodings%27)

another solution is: In insert mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> `="\xe2\x82\xa9"` <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to directly input UTF-8 characters using thier Hex Encoding.

the `\xe2\x82\xa9` is Hex Encoding of `₩` (the currency symbol for North Korea) character.

ref: [Vim documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_45.html#45.4)

Note: If you did the above configuration but still you were not able to see Unicode characters well or type, check in your Terminal or Console configuration if  `Character encoding` was set to `UTF-8`.

Read also [Special characters in Vim](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/special-characters-in-vim/).

Comment: This also solved the issue of not being able to input Chinese characters for me.

Comment: Could someone expand on what `C-R ="\xe2\x82\xa9" <enter>` does?

Comment: @ussr1717828 that's the UTF-8 encoding form of `₩` (the currency symbol for North Korea) and that allow user directly to type literal `₩` by using its UTF-8 Hex coding with `Ctrl+R="..."` - Enter.